# Having a problem with Select * From statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using an unbound form in MS Access to:
1) select an "event venue" via combo box,
2) select pre-registered participants to the event via cascading combo box,
thus filling in form data such as last name, first name, etc from "Paticipants" table relative to each venue.

This all works...next I add data to four new fields based upon participant desired activities.

I need to now "read" all of the form data and send it to table "B" or "c" dependent upon the combo box selected "Venue". Tables "B" and "c" have corresponding fields equal to the form. Using the below code. The IF statement works fine, but when the command button is clicked, the `set rec=db.OpenRecordset("select * from " & strMytable & "")` line returns a "From clause error." I have tried all that I can think of....any help? Thanks in advance. Just trying to get this one database done. First time using Access. Thanks

```
Private Sub Command129_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
Dim strMytable As String

Set db = CurrentDb
If Me.Combo77.Value = "Cherry Creek 2019" Then
   strMytable = "CC tourny results"
ElseIf Me.Combo77.Value = "Pueblo 2019" Then
  strMytable = "pueblo tourny results"
End If

sec rec=db.OpenRecordset("select * from " & strMytable & "")

rec.AddNew
rec("Last Name") = Me.LastName.text
rec.Update

rec.Close
db.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: The line of your code which contains the query has unbalanced double quotes.  I doubt that what you pasted above would even compile.

Comment: Don't paste here, just update your question with the actual code.

Comment: Why do you have multiple tourney tables instead of 1 tourney table with another field for tourney ID?

Comment: Actually, there is nothing wrong with the quotes.

Comment: You could also simply do `db.OpenRecordset(strMytable)`, then you wouldn't need the [].

Comment: Multiple tables for right now till I get more experience as well as time constraints on the project. Thanks for the db.OpenRecordset (strMytable) tip. Thanks to each of you for your response. As I said, I am fumbling my way through this project.... at age 72.

Comment: Just referencing a table is fine if not filtering, and since your code is not filtering it would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The table name has spaces. Must enclose object names in [ ] in SQL statements when they have spaces or special characters. Also should be `set` instead of `sec`.

`Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("select * from [" & strMytable & "]")`

Text is wrong property, should be Value and since Value is default for data controls, don't even have to specify.

`rec("Last Name") = Me.LastName`

Instead of recordset code, could just execute an INSERT action.

`CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [" & strMytable & "]([Last Name]) VALUES('" & Me.LastName & "')"`

Comment: Thank you very much for the corrections, I was getting balder by the moment trying to figure it out as this is my first Access project.